# ANDed-ORed query in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to execute the following query which in Django which filters out a model based on both ANDed and ORed states collectively.

The query in SQL is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM WebReply WHERE (conversation_id = conversation_id AND (user_id = ids OR sent_to = ids))
```

This is what I wrote in Django, which throws error saying `non-keyword arg after keyword arg django`

```
web_reply_data = WebReply.objects.filter(conversation_id = conversation_id, 
                                                        (Q(user_id = ids) |  Q(sent_to = ids)))
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
web_reply_data = WebReply.objects.filter(conversation_id = conversation_id).filter( Q(user_id = ids) |  Q(sent_to = ids))
```